# O que é Reflection. Por que é útil?

Tags: c#, .net, característica-linguagem, reflexão

1. É recomendável usar em projetos?
2. Como usar?
3. Em quais situações **Reflection** pode ser usado?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Eu resolvi responder porque a resposta atualmente aceita e com muitos votos está essencialmente errada. Não é que tudo esteja errado, e entendo o motivo do erro, muita gente erra nisso, ate C# tem um pouco de confusão na terminologia e ajuda no erro, mas é uma questão de interpretação, C# oferece reflexão, não só introspecção, mas a maioria parte do que se usa não é reflexão. E a resposta está um pouco defasada. Já explico.

A definição dada na resposta fala de inspeção e [introspecção](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_introspection), não de reflexão. Especialmente a parte final nega o que de fato é reflexão.

Falarei do termo genérico e pegando um pouco sobre C#.

## O que é Reflection?

**Reflexão é a capacidade de modificar código**, especialmente em tempo de execução. Conforme [verbete da Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflective_programming). Não use a versão em português, ela não é boa para qualquer assunto.

Reflexão é tratar o código como se ele fosse um dado da aplicação.

Ele é um [mecanismo de metaprogramação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/276112/101). Curiosamente já vi algumas pessoas desprezando a metaprogramação e glorificando a reflexão, o que mostra que as pessoas não entendem bem o que são esses conceitos. E aí sim, eu concordo que as pessoas devem ficar longe dele, não é um mecanismo simples.

Reflexão e metaprogramação são ferramentas poderosas, mas que exigem um bom domínio da programação para usar bem. Em alguns casos só a introspecção não é tão problemática assim, afinal ela é *read only*, o potencial de estrego é menor.

Sim, isso é feito porque C# tem muitos [metadados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107111/101). Ao mesmo tempo a presença do mecanismo faz com que se pague um custo de memória mesmo que não o use (em C# é possível personalizar o *runtime* para não ter, mas não é tarefa simples e foge do padrão).

A reflexão em tempo de compilação tornou o termo um pouco defasado, falarei mais sobre.

E admito que informalmente as pessoas misturam introspecção com reflexão porque a introspecção é parte da reflexão, mas a maior parte do tempo as pessoas estão apenas introspectando. E há controvérsias onde começa uma e termina a outra][5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25198271/221800).

## É recomendável usar em projetos?

A questão de ser recomendável é um pouco complicada e pode esbarrar em opiniões. Eu acho que não é recomendável. Porque recomendar é falar para usar. E não é para usar... até que seja necessário. Existem casos que é necessário para obter um resultado ou há casos que o custo compensa os benefícios.

Ela gera custo de processamento e em alguns casos é bem pesado, tornando a aplicação extremamente lenta. Você pode pagar esse custo? Tem certeza que não pode fazer de outra forma?

Existem opções melhores mesmo nos casos que alguma reflexão é necessária.

## Em quais situações Reflection pode ser usado?

Já pensou em usar *generics*, ou o acesso direto com uma informação que você já tem? São raros os casos que você consegue fazer algo útil sem saber como o tipo é estruturado, e se você sabe não precisa desse recurso. Ele é bom quando não se sabe o que tem ali.

Se você receber um JSON que desconhece a estrutura e quer criar um tipo para esses dados e isso requer reflexão. Ótimo, bom uso. Mas depois o que fará com o objeto criado por esse tipo, se a aplicação não sabe como ele é, dá para colocar na tela de forma genérica, ou gravar em algum lugar, provavelmente serializado, que é a forma que já tinha. Percebe que não dá para fazer algo específico, então dificilmente precisa criar uma classe para ele?

Em alguns casos ele é usado para dar alguma produtividade. Nos casos que é só para economizar digitação não vale a pena. Mas há casos que pode dar mais robustez quando dá manutenção e uma modificação acerta outras partes do código.

Tem que tomar cuidado porque se não usar isso muito bem a robustez se perde por completo. E em muitos casos só é necessário porque o *design* ou arquitetura da aplicação está ruim. Mesmo nos casos que seja interessante, pode haver maneiras melhores.

Uma maneira melhor é o uso reflexivo em tempo de compilação que dá mais robustez e até mais eficiência. O compilador tem muitas informações sobre o código e um bom pode dar uma capacidade enorme de introspecção. E o do C# é sensacional para isso desde a criação do [.NET Compiler Platform, vulgo Roslyn](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82756/101).

Embora sempre foi possível, mais recentemente algumas coisas foram facilitadas para [geração de código de fonte](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-c-source-generators/) durante a compilação, facilitando a reflexão (real) em tempo de compilação. E quase todos os casos de uso de reflexão deveria optar por esse mecanismo e não a reflexão clássica em tempo de execução.

Mas será difícil fazer as pessoas acostumarem, em geral é difícil ensinar truques novos para cães velhos e on cães novos não procuram os melhores e mais modernos materiais, pegam só o que está mais fácil na internet, ou seja, o que é ultrapassado.

Se não dá ou não precisa disso tudo existem outros mecanismos um pouco melhores que a reflexão, e C# oferece alguns deles, como genericidade já falada, e o dinamismo de tipo como [`dynamic`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/161740/101), que também [deve ser evitado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203656/101), mas não em troca da reflexão que é pior.

Tentando estruturar cenários:

- Carregar módulos e classes do *assembly* e criar uma instância deles em tempo de execução.
- Obter os campos de um objeto.
- Em testes, criando objetos fictícios durante a inicialização da execução.
- Para criar bibliotecas genéricas para lidar com formatos diferentes sem reimplantações, às vezes referidas, ou usando vinculação tardia implícita.
- Construir novos tipos em tempo de execução.
- Examinar e instanciar tipos.
- Permitir alterar o valor de um campo marcado como `private` ou `protected` em uma biblioteca de terceiros.

Já que não são coisas ordinárias, é por conta e risco.

## Por que é útil?

Ela pode:

- dar mais produtividade.
- dar um poder e flexibilidade maior para códigos que precisam de certo dinamismo.
- substituir um trabalho árduo e maçante, dando mais robustez,
- melhora a eficiência se for feita em tempo de compilação.

Só espero que as pessoas não abusem disto, especialmente usando a reflexão em tempo de execução.

## Como usar?

Só [eu dei vários exemplos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A101%20reflex%C3%A3o), especialmente em C#, tem muita coisa no site sobre o assunto. Mas quase tudo é a reflexão de execução, que era predominante até então, mas agora a tendência será começar ter mais exemplos usando geração de código. E boa parte usa apenas a parte da introspecção.

Os exemplos da outra resposta são apenas de introspecção, poderia ser diferente com [`Reflection.Emit`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), ou técnicas mais modernas usando o Roslyn para gera código durante a compilação ou mesmo em tempo de execução. [Veja mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23708/101).

Não adiantaria eu colocar 2 ou 3 exemplos porque é possível de diversas formas, siga o *link* acima para ver outros.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 71):

Reflection é um termo usado para indicar a capacidade de obter metadados sobre o próprio programa compilado, em português pode-se referir a isso como reflexão mesmo.

### Como assim, metadados?

Obter informações sobre os tipos de dados, de forma dinâmica, é muito importante para códigos que atuam sobre objetos que não se conhece em tempo de design. É muito usado em bibliotecas que se propõem a lidar com objetos de tipos que elas desconhecem em sua concepção.

O ASP.NET MVC por exemplo, só é um projeto possível por causa da reflexão. De que forma ele poderia chamar os métodos dos controllers, que ele nem conhece?

Visto, isso é preciso dizer que reflexão não é sempre rápido, é necessário verificar permissões, o nível de segurança em que o código está rodando, entre outras. Por isso, quando se obtém um resultado qualquer vindo através da reflexão, geralmente essas informações são colocadas em cache, ou seja, salvas em memória.

### É recomendável?

Depende do uso:

- **sim, é recomendável:** para criar comportamentos dinâmicos usando atributos, a única opção é reflexão
- **sim, é recomendável:** para chamar método que não se conhece durante a concepção do sistema, também é a única opção
- **não, é abuso fazer isso:** chamar um método, de uma classe conhecida em design-time usando reflexão... é absurdo

Existem tantas formas de usar reflexão que eu poderia continuar essa lista por muito tempo. Então mais vale o seguinte conselho: **bom senso**.

### Como usar?

Existem alguns vetores de uso de reflexão que eu conheço. Para demonstrá-los, vamos considerar primeiramente a seguinte classe:

```
public class Pessoa
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

- **Expressões Lambda:** esse é um vetor de reflexão, pois é possível usar expressões lambda para chegar aos tipos, métodos entre outros objetos refletidos, que tenham sido usados na expressão. É comumente utilizado para tornar fortemente tipada a obtenção de objetos refletidos de membros de uma classe, antes disso só era possível obter esses objetos indicando uma string com o nome do método.

  ```
  Expression<Func<Pessoa, object>> expr = p => p.Nome;
  var lambda = (LambdaExpression)expr;
  var cast = lambda.Body as UnaryExpression;
  var member = (cast != null ? cast.Operand : lambda.Body) as MemberExpression;
  var propInfo = member.Member as PropertyInfo;
  Console.WriteLine(propInfo.Name); // "Nome"
  ```
- **typeof(Tipo):** essa é uma das formas mais comuns de obter informações refletidas do sistema. Serve para obter informações sobre o tipo indicado diretamente.

  ```
  var tipo = typeof(Pessoa);
  Console.WriteLine(tipo.Name); // "Pessoa"
  ```
- **obj.GetType():** tão comum quando `typeof`, mas ao invés de se referir a um tipo diretamente, refere-se ao tipo do objeto em questão: mas tem um detalhe, não é do tipo declarado da variável, mas sim do objeto em si.

  ```
  var p = new Pessoa();    
  var tipo = p.GetType();
  Console.WriteLine(tipo.IsSealed); // "false"
  ```
- **Assembly:** é usada para obter tipos em larga escala: por exemplo, para escanear todos os tipos existentes em um assembly, ou então em todos os assemblies carregados.

  ```
  // localizando um tipo, dentre todos os tipos carregados
  var todosOsTiposCarregados = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
      .GetAssemblies()
      .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
      .Where(t => t.Name == "Pessoa");
  ```

### E o namespace Reflection.Emit?

Não está claro na minha mente se considero isso reflexão ou não. Mas de qualquer forma, é necessário usar reflexão para gerar código dinamicamente, então tem uma conexão.

Como disse, esse namespace contém classes usadas para gerar código dinamicamente... e então compilá-los. Lembra do que eu falei sobre cache de reflexão... compilar métodos é um bom alvo de cache, pois depois de compilado os futuros usos serão muitíssimo rápidos.

**Referências:**

- [Reflexão (programação)](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflex%C3%A3o_%28programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o%29)
- [Reflexão (C# e Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms173183.aspx)
- [Reflection (computer programming)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29)