# Como utilizar o Reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, reflexão

Como e porque utilizar o Reflection? Tem muita utilidade prática no dia a dia? Sua utilização oferece algum ganho para o sistema em si?

Comment: Excelente pergunta (já favoritei). Acho que se aplica não apenas ao mundo .NET mas a outras plataformas como Java também.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Há outra questão que responde isso muito bem, com mais detalhes, mas o intuito desta resposta é ser um pouco mais rápida e sucinta que o link a seguir: [O que é Reflection, por que é útil? Como usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13089/o-que-%C3%A9-reflection-por-que-%C3%A9-%C3%BAtil-como-usar)

## Como e porque utilizar o Reflection?

O `Reflection`, no Framework .NET, é uma funcionalidade em que é possível ler os dados de um objeto quanto à sua classe, ou seja, obtendo informações sobre:

- Propriedades da classe;
- Métodos;
- Outros valores.

Ele não é exclusivo do Framework .NET. Outras linguagens de programação, como o Java, por exemplo, também possuem a funcionalidade de `Reflection`.

## Tem muita utilidade prática no dia a dia?

Muitas, eu diria. O Entity Framework, por exemplo, usa extensivamente `Reflection` para mapear dados de um banco de dados para objetos de um modelo.

Em um código que desenvolvi aqui, consigo ler as propriedades de um objeto em C# utilizando o seguinte:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Extrai as propriedades de um objeto.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="objeto"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> ExtrairPropertiesDeObjeto(Object objeto)
    {
        return objeto.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public |
                               BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
    }
```

O retorno será de uma lista de `PropertyInfo`, em que eu posso obter o nome da propriedade, o valor dela, o nível de proteção, etc. No meu caso, utilizo para transformar o objeto em uma sentença SQL inteira preenchida com parâmetros. É apenas um código para todas as tabelas do sistema, sendo que as informações de cada tabela estão anotadas como propriedades e atributos de uma classe.

O código a seguir extrai as propriedades de um objeto cuja classe está com o attribute `[Column]`:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Obter as colunas da tabela segundo as colunas anotadas com o Atrribute Column.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected IEnumerable<String> ExtrairColunas()
    {
        foreach (var propertyInfo in ExtrairPropertiesDeObjeto(Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T))))
        {
            var columnAttribute = (ColumnAttribute)propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ColumnAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault();
            if (columnAttribute != null)
            {
                yield return columnAttribute.Name;
            }
        }
    }
```

E a seleção é feita da seguinte forma:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="operadores"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override IEnumerable<T> Selecionar(IEnumerable<Operador> operadores)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var obj = new Database())
            {
                var sSql =
                    "SELECT ";

                foreach (var coluna in ExtrairColunas())
                {
                    sSql += VirgulaOuEspaco + " t." + coluna;
                }

                sSql += " from " + ExtrairNomeTabela() + " t ";

                foreach (var operador in operadores)
                {
                    sSql += WhereOuAnd + " t." + operador;
                }

                var parametros =
                    operadores.Where(o => o.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Igual)))
                        .Select(o2 => ((Igual)o2).ParametroOracle)
                        .ToList();
                var dataTable = obj.ConsultarSQl(ConexaoBancoDados, sSql, parametros);

                return Transliterar(dataTable.Rows);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            ReiniciarWhereEVirgula();
        }
    }
```

O sistema inteiro usa este método para montar `SELECTS`. A única coisa que passo para a classe de repositório é um objeto.

## Sua utilização oferece algum ganho para o sistema em si?

Eu diria que é uma pergunta retórica. O `Reflection` oferece uma gama de funcionalidades e capacidades extras para a aplicação, em que a alternativa seria escrever muito mais código.

A base dos Frameworks atuais é sobretudo em cima de `Reflection`.

Comment: Essa pergunta foi feita, porque às vezes não vejo praticidade de saber propriedades de um objeto e seu tipo, pois o tenho declarado em meu código.

Comment: @pnet Bom, se precisar, posso ir dando exemplos de como fazer.

Comment: Sempre é bom, apesar de deixar claro que a intenção aqui não é código para ver, mas sim, aprender e abstrair tudo quanto ao que foi perguntado. Mas ter um exemplo prático é sempre bom sim. Vou mudar de trabalho e pra onde vou, preciso desses conceitos.