# Reflection Emit, para que serve?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, reflexão

Passando um código para MVC, vi que lá tinha um `Label label= new Label();` que estava sublinhado com vermelho, ao clicar para ver as sugestões, vi as seguintes:

```
using System.Web.Ui.WebControls

using System.Reflection.Emit
```

Me bateu a duvida, pra que serve esse Reflection Emit?

Vi algumas coisas na net, principalmente no site da MS, mas não consegui entender o uso dele.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

É um recurso raramente usado. O programador "normal" provavelmente nunca o usará.

Essencialmente ele serve para criar um Assembly da [CIL](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language). Ou seja, ele gera o "código de máquina" da máquina virtual do .NET. É uma forma simplificada de criar um código de baixo nível. Ele se preocupa em montar o formato adequado para que um código de máquina seja entendido pelo .NET.

Desta forma é possível criar código arbitrário em tempo de execução para ser gravado em uma DLL (um arquivo *assembly*) ou para ser executado logo em seguida. Seja para criar alguma funcionalidade que só pode ser montada em tempo de execução mesmo, seja para obter uma otimização maior.

- O [LINQ](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query), por exemplo, faz muito uso dele para montar suas árvores de expressão.
- [Serialização](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/ms973893(v=msdn.10)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) também costuma usá-lo.
- Criação de objetos *proxy* usa este recurso.
- Algumas situações a linguagem não dá suporte a algum recurso que só possível alcançar com emissão do código de baixo nível passando por cima da linguagem de alto nível.
- [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) é um dos inúmeros ORMs que usam esta emissão.

O seu uso é intenso em um compilador ou alguma ferramenta ([AOP](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_orientada_a_aspecto) e [mockers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object), são exemplos) que altere o *bytecode* da aplicação desenvolvida para o .NET (ou qualquer outra implementação compatível, como o Mono, claro).

Agora ele é ainda menos necessário. Na maioria dos casos é mais interessante usar os serviços do novo compilador chamado [.NET Compiler Platform](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) (antigo projeto Roslyn) disponível no C# 6/Visual Studio 2015. A geração de código em tempo de execução é muito mais fácil e poderosa na maioria dos casos.

[Fonte de informação oficial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/3y322t50(v=vs.100)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Referência do *namespace*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Agora deu pra entender! rsrs muito obrigado!