# Recuperar o valor de um campo gerado dinamicamente

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, viewmodel

Bom dia. Pessoal gostaria de saber como faço para recuperar o valor do controle  que é gerado dinamicamente no meu formulário em tempo de execução?
Tipo abaixo na imagem tenho uma classe que traz todas as propriedades dos controles para ser mostrado na View de Cliente. Nela trago o tipo de controle HTML, a classe CSS que vai ser utilizada, a order que vai aparecer esse controle na página,etc, tudo já pré-configurado no banco de dados:
[image: Configurações do Controle]

No momento que efetuo o submit e a model não é válida, não estou conseguindo recuperar o valor digitado no campo como mostra a página abaixo:
[image: Tela Cadastro de Cliente]
[image: Formulário não está recuperando o valor Digitado]

Estou tentando fazer funcionar esse tipo de geração de controles dinâmico, devido pensar em uma sistema de cadastro onde possa ter vários clientes com telas de cadastro diferentes, com campos diferentes, nomes de exibição diferentes, a ordem que cada label ou input aparece, etc. Pensando nesse cenário fica fácil montar todas telas de acordo com os requisitos de telas com digamos 10 clientes com telas diferentes, sem precisar mexer nas minhas Views.
Tentei fazer dessa forma, mas se alguém estiver uma ideia melhor que possa me ajudar a gerar esses controles dinamicamente sem precisar criar várias views no projeto agradeço ou me ajudar seguindo essa lógica que fiz.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ProjetoModeloDDD.MVC.ViewModels
{
    public class ClienteViewModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int ClienteId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o campo Nome")]
        [MaxLength(150, ErrorMessage = "Máximo {0} caracteres")]
        [MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Minimo {0} caracteres")]
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o campo Sobrenome")]
        [MaxLength(150, ErrorMessage = "Máximo {0} caracteres")]
        [MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Mínimo {0} caracteres")]
        public string Sobrenome { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o campo Endereço")]
        [MaxLength(150, ErrorMessage = "Máximo {0} caracteres")]
        [MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Mínimo {0} caracteres")]
        [Display(Name = "Endereço")]
        public string Endereco { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Ponto de Ref.")]
        public string PontoReferencia { get; set; }
        public string Telefone { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Data de Nascimento")]
        public DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o campo E-mail")]
        [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Máximo {0} caracteres")]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Preencha um E-mail válido")]
        [DisplayName("E-mail")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }

        public bool Ativo { get; set; }
        public virtual IEnumerable<ProdutoViewModel> Produtos { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<MenuConfigViewModel> MenuConfigViewModels { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Código da View Create Cliente

```
@using ProjetoModeloDDD.MVC.Helpers
@model  ProjetoModeloDDD.MVC.ViewModels.ClienteViewModel


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";


}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>ClienteViewModel</h4>
        <hr />fma

        @if (Model.MenuConfigViewModels != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in Model.MenuConfigViewModels)
            {
                if (item.TagHtml.Equals("input"))
                {
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @HtmlHelpers.MyInputHelper(item.Name, item.Name, "", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control text-box single-line input-validation-error" })
                        @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nome, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })*@
                    </div>
                }

            }

        } 

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: Por favor disponibilize a classe `ClienteViewModel`?

Comment: É melhor você tirar as imagens e colocar o código. Fica mais fácil de ajudar.

Comment: Pronto alterado e incluído ós códigos das ViewsModels

Comment: Não consegui entender o que deseja. Como assim dinâmico? Pelas suas imagens, está preenchendo apenas um campo. Poderia explicar melhor o que deseja?

Comment: Por exemplo digamos que teria 10 clientes com telas de cadastros diferentes. Criar 10 views não seria nada viável, então gostaria criar somente 1 view onde monto todo os campos HTML por um foreach informando quando é o tipo de controle se é input, label, table, etc, de acordo com os requisitos do cliente, assim posso especificar até qual classe CSS aquele campo vai utilizar etc.

Comment: Acho que entendi, sua aplicação é personalizada para cada cliente que vai utilizar ela, e para cada um os campos do formulário são diferentes, é isso ? Se for, isso é um dos motivos pelo qual você deveria pesquisar sobre SOLID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você quer é um (ou todos) dos princípios pelo qual existe [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design))

Crie uma interface, nela coloque todos os campos que vão existir obrigatoriamente para todos os 10, 100, N clientes

```
public interface IClienteDaAplicacaoModel
{
    Int32 ClienteId {get;set;}
    String CPF {get;set;}
    String Email {get;set;}
}
```

Agora para cada um dos clientes, crie um modelo concreto que herda a interface

```
public sealed class ClienteXModel : IClienteDaAplicacaoModel
{
    public String CampoEspecificoDoClienteX {get;set;}
    public String CNPJ {get;set;}
}

public sealed class ClienteYModel : IClienteDaAplicacaoModel
{
    public Int64 TelefoneContato {get;set;}
}

public sealed class...outros clientes
```

A partir dai você trabalha com a Interface e não com as implementações dela, e usa [Reflection](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13089/o-que-%C3%A9-reflection-por-que-%C3%A9-%C3%BAtil-como-usar) para pegar os campos de cada implementação de acordo com o uso

Além dos links acima, seguem mais alguns sobre SOLID e Reflection

- https://scotch.io/bar-talk/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design
- http://www.eduardopires.net.br/2015/01/solid-teoria-e-pratica/
- http://netcoders.com.br/blog/aplicando-solid-com-c-srp/
- http://netcoders.com.br/blog/aplicando-solid-com-c-ocp/
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_reflection.htm
- http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/1518/entendendo-o-reflection-aspnet_csharp.aspx

*Utilizei sealed nos exemplos concretos, mas elas podem ser abstract ou não sealed se você quiser que elas possam ser herdadas por outros clientes (vamos supor que o cliente Z tem tudo do cliente X e da interface, ai neste caso bastaria herdar X em Z ao invés de ter os mesmos campos de X em Z novamente)