# Preencher classe com resultado do banco

Tags: c#, sql-server

Boa tarde a todos. Tenho uma necessidade gigante de conseguir montar uma situação.

Eu tenho um objeto `DataTable` com o resultado com a coluna `"ID_CLIENTE"`.

Eu tenho um objeto `Cliente` com a propriedate `ID_CLIENTE`.

Existe alguma forma de preencher o objeto `Cliente` com os dados do `DataTable` automaticamente, apenas passando o tipo do objeto `Cliente` e ele saber que a coluna `"ID_CLIENTE"` do `DataTable` tem de ser bindado na propriedade `"ID_CLIENTE"` do objeto `Cliente` ?

Consegui ser claro?

> Classe Cliente

```
public class Cliente
{
    public int ID_CLIENTE { get; set; }
    public string NOME_CLIENTE { get; set; }
    public DateTime DT_NASC_CLIENTE { get; set; }
}
```

> Carregando DataTable

```
SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection("STRING_CONEXAO");
SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TAB_CLIENTE", conexao);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

try
{
    conexao.Open();
    dt.Load(comando.ExecuteReader());
    conexao.Close();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    if (conexao.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
        conexao.Close();
    throw;
}
```

Comment: Como você carrega o `Datatable`? e como está essa classe Cliente, pode fornecer todo o código dessa classe?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Alterei a pergunta com os dados que pediu.

Comment: Cara, você precisa é de um ORM (like Entity Framework).

Comment: Você quer a conversão de um `DataTable` em uma `Class` ou pode propor uma solução ideal?

Comment: Gostaria da conversão do `DataTable` na `Class`, mas aceito propor a solução sim, com certeza.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solução ideal, é fazer a lista do tipo que necessita com o código logo abaixo:

```
List<Cliente> clientes = new List<Cliente>();
SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection("STRING_CONEXAO");
SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID_CLIENTE,NOME_CLIENTE,DT_NASC_CLIENTE 
                                     FROM TAB_CLIENTE", conexao);

using (SqlDataReader reader = comando.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            clientes.Add(new Cliente
            {
                ID_CLIENTE = reader.GetInt32(0),
                NOME_CLIENTE = reader.GetString(1),
                DT_NASC_CLIENTE = reader.GetDateTime(2)
            });                        
        }
    }
}
return clientes;
```

<sub>***Observação:*** na sua [SQL](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) foi editada e colocado os 3 campos em ordem para ser utilizado no código</sub>

---

Por curiosidade se esse [`DataTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx) vier de algo que não é produzido por você pode utilizar esse código (que é um [método de extensão](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb383977.aspx) utilizando [reflection](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13089/o-que-%C3%A9-reflection-por-que-%C3%A9-%C3%BAtil-como-usar)):

<sub>**Observação:** *os campos da classe tem que ser igual ao mesmos nomes e tipos de campo para funcionar a [reflection](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13089/o-que-%C3%A9-reflection-por-que-%C3%A9-%C3%BAtil-como-usar)*</sub>

Crie uma classe com o seguinte `layout`:

```
public static class MyExt
{
    public static List<T> ToListOf<T>(this DataTable dt)
    {
        const BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;
        var columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
            .Select(c => c.ColumnName)
            .ToList();
        var objectProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties(flags);
        var targetList = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(dataRow =>
        {
            var instanceOfT = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

            foreach (var properties in objectProperties
                 .Where(properties => columnNames.Contains(properties.Name)
                   && dataRow[properties.Name] != DBNull.Value))
            {
                properties.SetValue(instanceOfT, dataRow[properties.Name], null);
            }
            return instanceOfT;
        }).ToList();

        return targetList;
    }
}
```

<sub>[Código retirado SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29877551/6797930)</sub>

***Como utilizar?***

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
List<Cliente> clientes = dt.ToListOf<Cliente>();
```

---

**Outra forma poderia ser assim:**

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
List<Cliente> result = dt.AsEnumerable()
            .Select(s => new  Cliente
            {
                ID_CLIENTE = s.Field<int>("ID_CLIENTE"),
                NOME_CLIENTE = s.Field<string>("NOME_CLIENTE"),
                DT_NASC_CLIENTE = s.Field<DateTime>("DT_NASC_CLIENTE")
            })
            .ToList();
```

***Referencias:***

- [Classe DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Converting DataTable to List of class](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/30714/converting-datatable-to-list-of-class)
- [Métodos de extensão (Guia de Programação em C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb383977.aspx)
- [O que é Reflection, por que é útil? Como usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13089/o-que-%C3%A9-reflection-por-que-%C3%A9-%C3%BAtil-como-usar)
- [Reflexão (c#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/mt656691.aspx)

Comment: Virgilio, é exatamente isso que eu precisava. Maravilha. Com esse método de extensão, eu consigo fazer o bind de qualquer consulta do bando, desde que eu crie uma classe com as propriedades com o mesmo nome. EXATAMENTE isso que eu preciso! MUITO OBRIGADO.