# Erro ao consultar dados no JTable com Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

O seguinte erro da ao consultar os dados:

> ```
>  INFO: HHH000182: No default (no-argument) constructor for class:
>  Classes.Funcionario (class must be instantiated by Interceptor)
>
>  Hibernate: select funcionari0_.ID_Funcionario as ID_Funci1_0_,
>  funcionari0_.`Data de Admissao` as Data2_0_, funcionari0_.`Data de
>  Demissao` as Data3_0_, funcionari0_.Nome as Nome4_0_,
>  funcionari0_.`Estado Civil` as Estado5_0_, funcionari0_.Sexo as
>  Sexo6_0_, funcionari0_.CEP as CEP7_0_, funcionari0_.CPF as CPF8_0_,
>  funcionari0_.RG as RG9_0_, funcionari0_.`Data de Nascimento` as
>  Data10_0_, funcionari0_.Estado as Estado11_0_, funcionari0_.Cidade as
>  Cidade12_0_, funcionari0_.Bairro as Bairro13_0_, funcionari0_.Endereco
>  as Enderec14_0_, funcionari0_.TEL as TEL15_0_, funcionari0_.CEL as
>  CEL16_0_, funcionari0_.Email as Email17_0_, funcionari0_.Cargo as
>  Cargo18_0_, funcionari0_.`Nivel de Escolaridade` as Nivel19_0_ from
>  funcionario funcionari0_ 
>
> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity:  : Classes.Funcionario
> ```

TELA DO JTABLE

```
package Telas;

import Classes.Funcionario;
import Hibernate.HibernateUtil;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;


 */
public class Tela_ConsultarFuncionario extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {


    List <Funcionario> funcionarios  = new ArrayList<>();

    String [] Colunas = new String [] {"nome,datadeAdmissao,estadoCivil,sexo,cep,cpf,rg,datadeNascimento,estado,cidade,bairro,endereco,tel,cel,email,cargo,niveldeEscolaridade"};
    String [] [] Dados = new String [10] [16];



    public Tela_ConsultarFuncionario() {


        initComponents();

        Tbl_Funcionarios.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);

}                    


    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        String [][] Dados = new String [funcionarios.size()] [17];

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

      Query query = session.createQuery("select c from Funcionario c");
       funcionarios = query.list();

         int i = 0;



          String [] Colunas = new String[]{"nome,datadeAdmissao,estadoCivil,sexo,cep,cpf,rg,datadeNascimento,estado,cidade,bairro,endereco,tel,cel,email,cargo,niveldeEscolaridade"};


         while( i<funcionarios.size() )
        {

            Dados [i][0] = funcionarios.get(i).getDatadeAdmissao();
            Dados [i][1] = funcionarios.get(i).getNome();
            Dados [i][2] = funcionarios.get(i).getDatadeNascimento();
            Dados [i][3] = funcionarios.get(i).getSexo();
            Dados [i][4] = funcionarios.get(i).getEstadoCivil();
            Dados [i][5] = funcionarios.get(i).getCep();
            Dados [i][6] = funcionarios.get(i).getCpf();
            Dados [i][7] = funcionarios.get(i).getRg();
            Dados [i][8] = funcionarios.get(i).getEstado();
            Dados [i][9] = funcionarios.get(i).getCidade();
            Dados [i][10] = funcionarios.get(i).getBairro();
            Dados [i][11] = funcionarios.get(i).getEndereco();
            Dados [i][12] = funcionarios.get(i).getTel();
            Dados [i][13] = funcionarios.get(i).getCel();
            Dados [i][14] = funcionarios.get(i).getEmail();
            Dados [i][15] = funcionarios.get(i).getNiveldeEscolaridade();
            Dados [i][16] = funcionarios.get(i).getCargo();

          i++;

        }


        session.beginTransaction();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();


        DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel(Dados,Colunas);
       Tbl_Funcionarios.setModel( modelo );  





    }                                        


}
```

TELA FUNCIONARIO

```
package Classes;

import java.io.Serializable;


public class Funcionario implements Serializable {



    private Integer iDFuncionario;
    private String datadeAdmissao;
    private String datadeDemissao;
    private String nome;
    private String estadoCivil;
    private String sexo;
    private String cep;
    private String cpf;
    private String rg;
    private String datadeNascimento;
    private String estado;
    private String cidade;
    private String bairro;
    private String endereco;
    private String tel;
    private String cel;
    private String email;
    private String cargo;
    private String niveldeEscolaridade;

    public Funcionario(String nome,String datadeAdmissao,String datadeDemissao,String estadoCivil,String sexo,String cep,String cpf,String rg,String datadeNascimento,String estado
    ,String cidade,String bairro,String endereco,String tel,String cel,String email,String cargo,String niveldeEscolaridade) {
      this.nome=nome;
      this.datadeAdmissao=datadeAdmissao;
      this.datadeDemissao=datadeDemissao;
      this.estadoCivil=estadoCivil;
      this.sexo=sexo;
      this.cep=cep;
      this.cpf=cpf;
      this.rg=rg;
      this.datadeNascimento=datadeNascimento;
      this.estado=estado;
      this.cidade=cidade;
      this.bairro=bairro;
      this.endereco=endereco;
      this.tel=tel;
      this.cel=cel;
      this.email=email;
      this.cargo=cargo;
      this.niveldeEscolaridade=niveldeEscolaridade;
    }

    public Funcionario(Integer iDFuncionario) {
     this.iDFuncionario=iDFuncionario;
    }



    public Integer getiDFuncionario() {
        return iDFuncionario;
    }


    public void setiDFuncionario(Integer iDFuncionario) {
        this.iDFuncionario = iDFuncionario;
    }

    public String getDatadeAdmissao() {
        return datadeAdmissao;
    }

    public void setDatadeAdmissao(String datadeAdmissao) {
        this.datadeAdmissao = datadeAdmissao;
    }

    public String getDatadeDemissao() {
        return datadeDemissao;
    }

    public void setDatadeDemissao(String datadeDemissao) {
        this.datadeDemissao = datadeDemissao;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getEstadoCivil() {
        return estadoCivil;
    }

    public void setEstadoCivil(String estadoCivil) {
        this.estadoCivil = estadoCivil;
    }

    public String getSexo() {
        return sexo;
    }

    public void setSexo(String sexo) {
        this.sexo = sexo;
    }

    public String getCep() {
        return cep;
    }

    public void setCep(String cep) {
        this.cep = cep;
    }

    public String getCpf() {
        return cpf;
    }

    public void setCpf(String cpf) {
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }

    public String getRg() {
        return rg;
    }

    public void setRg(String rg) {
        this.rg = rg;
    }

    public String getDatadeNascimento() {
        return datadeNascimento;
    }

    public void setDatadeNascimento(String datadeNascimento) {
        this.datadeNascimento = datadeNascimento;
    }

    public String getEstado() {
        return estado;
    }

    public void setEstado(String estado) {
        this.estado = estado;
    }

    public String getCidade() {
        return cidade;
    }

    public void setCidade(String cidade) {
        this.cidade = cidade;
    }

    public String getBairro() {
        return bairro;
    }

    public void setBairro(String bairro) {
        this.bairro = bairro;
    }

    public String getEndereco() {
        return endereco;
    }

    public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }

    public String getTel() {
        return tel;
    }

    public void setTel(String tel) {
        this.tel = tel;
    }

    public String getCel() {
        return cel;
    }

    public void setCel(String cel) {
        this.cel = cel;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getCargo() {
        return cargo;
    }

    public void setCargo(String cargo) {
        this.cargo = cargo;
    }

    public String getNiveldeEscolaridade() {
        return niveldeEscolaridade;
    }

    public void setNiveldeEscolaridade(String niveldeEscolaridade) {
        this.niveldeEscolaridade = niveldeEscolaridade;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (iDFuncionario != null ? iDFuncionario.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Funcionario)) {
            return false;
        }
        Funcionario other = (Funcionario) object;
        if ((this.iDFuncionario == null && other.iDFuncionario != null) || (this.iDFuncionario != null && !this.iDFuncionario.equals(other.iDFuncionario))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Classes.Funcionario[ iDFuncionario=" + iDFuncionario + " ]";
    }

}
```

TELA MAPEAMENTO DO FUNCIONARIO

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="Classes.Funcionario" table="funcionario" >
  <id name="iDFuncionario" column="ID_Funcionario">
      <generator class="native"/>
  </id>
        <property name="datadeAdmissao" type="string" length ="50" column="`Data de Admissao`" />
        <property name="datadeDemissao" type="string" length ="50" column="`Data de Demissao`"/>
        <property name="nome" type="string" length="50" column="Nome"/>
        <property name="estadoCivil" type="string" length="50" column="`Estado Civil`"/>
        <property name="sexo" type="string" length ="50" column="Sexo"/>
        <property name="cep" type="string" length ="50" column="CEP"/>
        <property name="cpf" type="string" length ="50" column="CPF"/>
        <property name="rg" type="string" length ="50" column="RG"/>
        <property name="datadeNascimento" type="string" length ="50" column="`Data de Nascimento`"/>
        <property name="estado" type="string" length ="50" column="Estado"/>
        <property name="cidade" type="string" length ="50" column="Cidade"/>
        <property name="bairro" type="string" length ="50" column="Bairro" />
        <property name="endereco" type="string" length ="50" column="Endereco"/>
        <property name="tel" type="string" length ="50" column="TEL"/>
        <property name="cel" type="string" length ="50" column="CEL"/>
        <property name="email" type="string" length ="50" column="Email"/>
        <property name="cargo" type="string" length ="50" column="Cargo"/>
        <property name="niveldeEscolaridade" type="string" length ="50" column="`Nivel de Escolaridade`"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Adicione sua classe funcionario.

Comment: de que maneira ?

Comment: Eu quis dizer adicionar a classe na pergunta, esta classe está envolvida no erro também.

Comment: Ah ta,não tinha entendido kkkkk

Comment: Não domino hibernate, mas o erro parece estar relacionado a falta de um construtor padrao, no caso, `public Funcionario(){...}`

Comment: Dica, não use o snipet para códigos java, basta colar o código, seleciona-lo e clicar em `{}`

Comment: Blz,muda alguma,fica melhor assim ?

Comment: Pelo que li no SOEn, o hibernate exige que se tenha um construtor default, ou seja, aquele sem argumentos como exemplifiquei no comentário anterior, pois ele usa reflexão para criar o bean. Primeiro ele cria um objeto vazio e depois vai preenchendo com os getters e setters conforme for necessário. Quando você personaliza o construtor com argumentos, o construtor padrao precisa ser implementado de forma explicita na classe.

Comment: ah,ta vou ver mexer aqui para ver

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Comment: agora mudou o erro

Comment: Ai já é outro problema, o que demandaria outra pergunta diferente. o erro da pergunta se resolveu com a dica passada. Converti como resposta para melhorar a visibilidade da dica para outras pessoas.

Comment: Não se esqueça de citar esta pergunta na nova, para facilitar a analise de quem responder :)

Comment: Só criar outra pergunta então ?

Comment: Sim, e adicionar a pilha completa do erro como fez nessa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme [esta resposta do SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25452112/5524514), o hibernate exige que se tenha um construtor default, ou seja, aquele sem argumentos como exemplifiquei nos comentários, pois ele usa [Reflection](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13089/28595) para criar o bean. Primeiro ele cria um objeto vazio e depois vai preenchendo com os setters conforme for necessário. Quando você personaliza o construtor com argumentos, o construtor padrão precisa ser implementado de forma explicita na classe.

Creio que adicionando um construtor padrão da forma abaixo resolva o erro:

```
public Funcionario(){ 

}
```