# Obter todas classes que implementam uma interface genérica

Tags: c#, reflexão

Tenho uma interface semelhante a esta:

```
public interface InterfaceA<T>
{
   T Exemplo();
}
```

E outras classes implementam ela.

```
public class ExemploA : InterfaceA<Int32>
{
    Int32 Exemplo();
}

public class ExemploB : InterfaceA<String>
{
    String Exemplo();
}
```

Pesquisando achei [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26750/6163123) resposta no SOen, porém não consigo obter o `type` da interface sem o `generics`.

```
var type = typeof(InterfaceA); //erro
```

Alguém sabe como posso obter o `type` das classes  `ExemploA`, `ExemploB`, buscando pela `InterfaceA`, dentro de um determinado `assembly`?

Comment: Você quer obter todas as classes que implementem **`InterfaceA`**. Certo?

Comment: Isto mesmo, independente que seja `InterfaceA<Int32>` ou `InterfaceA<String>`, listar todas que implementam `InterfaceA`

Comment: @MarcoGiovanni fiz mais um edição fazendo com que o `Linq` busca pelo tipo generic `InterfaceA<>` é uma boa também ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Com [linq](/questions/tagged/linq) para fazer uma busca por ***nome***:

```
var types = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                .Where(p => p.GetInterfaces().Where(c => c.Name.Contains("InterfaceA"))
                             .Any())                
                .ToList();
```

***ou***

A busca pelo tipo *genérico* da [`Interface`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/87d83y5b.aspx):

```
var types = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                .Where(p => p.GetInterfaces()
                             .Where(c => c.IsGenericType &&
                                    c.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(InterfaceA<>))
                                     .Any())                
                .ToList();
```

<sub>***Referências:***</sub>

- [Reflexão (c#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/mt656691.aspx)
- [Reflexão e tipos genéricos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms172334.aspx)
- [Propriedade Type.IsGenericTypeDefinition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.type.isgenerictypedefinition.aspx)
- [Propriedade MethodInfo.IsGenericMethodDefinition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.isgenericmethoddefinition.aspx)
- [O que é Reflection, por que é útil? Como usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13089/o-que-%C3%A9-reflection-por-que-%C3%A9-%C3%BAtil-como-usar)
- [Reflexão (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/mt656692.aspx)
- [interface (Referência de C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/87d83y5b.aspx)
- [Interfaces genéricas (Guia de Programação em C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/kwtft8ak.aspx)