# Usando annotations do model para controller C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Eu tenho este annotation em meu model

```
[ZoneamentoDados(fim = 2, inicio = 1, tamanho = 2, obs = "Tipo Registro")]
public String tipoRegistro { get; set; }
[ZoneamentoDados(fim = 54, inicio = 54, tamanho = 1, obs = "Sempre 1")]
```

preciso usar os valore fim, inicio e tamanho para separar `substring` no `controller`. Alguém pode me dizer como eu poderia usar estes `annotations` no `controller` ou indicar algum link para entender melhor?

Comment: http://www.macoratti.net/13/12/c_vdda.htm

Answer (score 1):

Neste caso você terá que trabalhar com [a famosa Reflection.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13089/20615)

Para isso, você precisará ler a propriedade selecionada e retornar o valor desejado.

Um exemplo seria algo parecido com isso:

```
public static int ObterValorInicio<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expr)
{
    var mexpr = expr.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (mexpr == null) return 0;
    if (mexpr.Member == null) return 0;
    //Busco o CustomAttribute ZoneamentoDados
    object[] attrs = mexpr.Member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ZoneamentoDados), false);
    if (attrs == null || attrs.Length == 0) return 0;
    //Seleciono o primeiro valor
    ZoneamentoDados desc = attrs[0] as ZoneamentoDados;
    if (desc == null) return 0;

    //Obtém o valor Inicio. Para obter outros valores, basta alterar, ex: return desc.Tamanho;
    return desc.Inicio;
}
```

Neste exemplo eu busco um **attributo custom** chamado `ZoneamentoDados` e retorno os valores. Caso encontre o valor, eu retorno o valor correspondente à propriedade desejada.

Veja um exemplo completo no [.NETFiddle aqui.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ctEQ9E)

Abaixo estão algumas referências para melhor compreensão:

- [Pass a C# property name as a parameter to an utility class method](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/69cce588-006e-4331-ac34-21967845ab34/pass-a-c-property-name-as-a-parameter-to-an-utility-class-method?forum=csharpgeneral)
- [Reflection - get attribute name and value on property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6637679/4843158)
- [Getting Expression Text for lambda Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7445911/4843158)

Caso o .NETFiddle exploda, abaixo está o exemplo completo:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace TestReflection
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var registro = new Registro();

            var inicio = ClassExtensions.ObterValorInicio(() => registro.tipoRegistro);
            Console.WriteLine(inicio);
        }
    }

    public class ZoneamentoDados : System.Attribute
    {
        public int Fim { get; set; }
        public int Inicio { get; set; }
        public int Tamanho { get; set; }
        public string Obs { get; set; }

        public ZoneamentoDados(int fim, int inicio, int tamanho, string obs)
        {
            Fim = fim;
            Inicio = inicio;
            Tamanho = tamanho;
            Obs = obs;
        }
        public ZoneamentoDados() { }
    }


    public class Registro
    {
        [ZoneamentoDados(Fim = 2, Inicio = 1, Tamanho = 2, Obs = "Tipo Registro")]
        public String tipoRegistro { get; set; }
    }

    public static class ClassExtensions
    {
        public static int ObterValorInicio<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expr)
        {
            var mexpr = expr.Body as MemberExpression;
            if (mexpr == null) return 0;
            if (mexpr.Member == null) return 0;
            object[] attrs = mexpr.Member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ZoneamentoDados), false);
            if (attrs == null || attrs.Length == 0) return 0;
            ZoneamentoDados desc = attrs[0] as ZoneamentoDados;
            if (desc == null) return 0;

            //Obtém o valor Inicio. Para obter outros valores, basta alterar, ex: return desc.Tamanho;
            return desc.Inicio;
        }
    }
}
```