# Comparando dois objeto e copiando condicionalmente

Tags: c#, .net, objetos

Tenho as seguintes classes:

```
public class Pessoal
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string CPF { get; set; }
    public string PIS { get; set; }
    public string NOME { get; set; }
    ...
    ...
    ... 
}


public class Dominio : DominioBase
{

    public Pessoal Pessoal { get; set; }

    public Pessoal PessoalAlteracao { get; set; }

}
```

Gostaria de copiar os atributos de `PessoalAlteracao` com os valores de `Pessoal`, mas somente quanto valor do atributo de `PessoalAlteracao` for igual a `null`.

Posso fazer através de um `if`:

```
PessoalAlteracao.CPF = PessoalAlteracao.CPF == null ? Pessoal.CPF : PessoalAlteracao.CPF;
```

Porém gostaria de usar uma forma mais simples, teria como criar um *loop*, pelos atributos e igualar testando os valores?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É possível fazer usando [reflexão (*reflection*)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13089/18246).

Tenha em mente que embora isso encurte bastante o código, pode ter uma execução mais lenta do que simplesmente escrever "na mão" propriedade por propriedade ou usando uma outra abordagem qualquer.

Dependendo de como estão as classes e da regra geral para essa substituição de valores, um clone seria uma escolha um pouco melhor — mesmo que ainda seja feito uso de reflexão. Mas não é possível afirmar nada sem conhecer melhor o cenário.

```
var pessoal = dominio.Pessoal;
var alteracao = dominio.PessoalAlteracao;

foreach(var prop in alteracao.GetType().GetProperties()) 
{
    if(prop.GetValue(alteracao, null) == null)
    {
        var novoValor = alteracao.GetType().GetProperties().First(p => p.Name == prop.Name)
                                 .GetValue(pessoal, null);
        prop.SetValue(alteracao, novoValor);
    }           
}
```

Exemplo completo

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    static Dominio _dominio = new Dominio
    {
        Pessoal = new Pessoal
        {
            ID = 1,
            CPF = "033",
            PIS = "123",
            NOME = "João"
        },

        PessoalAlteracao = new Pessoal
        {
            ID = 1,
            PIS = "987"
        }
    };

    public static void Main()
    {
        var pessoal = _dominio.Pessoal;
        var alteracao = _dominio.PessoalAlteracao;

        foreach(var prop in alteracao.GetType().GetProperties()) 
        {
            if(prop.GetValue(alteracao, null) == null)
            {
                var novoValor = alteracao.GetType().GetProperties()
                                .First(p => p.Name == prop.Name).GetValue(pessoal, null);
                prop.SetValue(alteracao, novoValor);
            }           
        }

        foreach(var prop in alteracao.GetType().GetProperties()) 
        {
           Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", prop.Name, prop.GetValue(alteracao, null));
        }

    }
}

public class Pessoal
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string CPF { get; set; }
    public string PIS { get; set; }
    public string NOME { get; set; }
}

public class Dominio
{
    public Pessoal Pessoal { get; set; }
    public Pessoal PessoalAlteracao { get; set; }

}
```

<sup>[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/g09rPB)</sup>

Comment: acho que novoValor, tem que receber do `pessoal` e não do `alteracao`

Comment: @RovannLinhalis pois é. Vou melhorar a resposta logo. Tô almocando agora, quando voltar ajeito. Obrigado.

Comment: @LINQ são uns 60 campos e por isto acho que no caso o reflection vai poder ser usado e irá facilitar a codificação, pois é somente uma tela de alteração básica. Vou testar qui para ver se impactará na performance, mas creio que não. Muito obrigado, pela paciência e ajuda com didática de ótima qualidade.

Comment: @Jota Por nada. Nem sempre reflection é um monstro, pra casos específicos ele é muito útil. Boa sorte aí =)

Answer (score 4):

A forma mais simples é esta:

```
PessoalAlteracao.CPF = PessoalAlteracao.CPF ?? Pessoal.CPF;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Operator/CoalescingAssigment.cs).

Todas as outras opções são mais complicadas. Algumas podem ter menos linhas (para poucas propriedades nem é), mas se tornam mais complexas de fazer, pode ter dificuldades em certos cenários (só funciona se clonar tudo no mesmo critério, o que pode não ser verdade hoje, ou pode deixar de ser amanhã) e a performance sofre.

Note que o critério adotado não funciona para tipos por valor, e deve ter vários. A não ser que use um tipo anulável para isto, o que poluiria o objeto com algo desnecessário só para atender um mecanismo que permite o programador digitar menos linhas. Ou dá resultado errado ou o conceito está errado e vai cobrar um dia por isto.

Eu não usaria reflexão em C# até que seja absolutamente necessário. Quando se começa abusar desse recurso é porque C# é a linguagem errada para este projeto.

Quase toda reflexão usada em C# é desnecessária.

É óbvio que se o objeto costuma ser clonado assim faz sentido colocar isto em um método e não ficar criando código para clonar em todo lugar que usar.

Eu nem questionei se precisa fazer este filtro se é nulo ou não. Pode ser que não precise, aí bastaria clonar de forma padrão, ainda que usaria reflexão também, mas nem precisaria escrever código próprio.

Comment: ♦ Não seria um clone, pois uma classe os dados originais e outra dados alterados (corrigidos) pelo usuário. Então ser for nulo preciso que seja igual (clone), senão preciso mantar o que foi informado pelo usuário. Muito obrigado pelo esclarecimento.

Comment: @Jota é uma clonagem condicional, mas é uma clonagem. Editei para te mostrar mais que não dá certo tentar automatizar isto.

Comment: Já me deparei com projetos que abusam de pattern ou complicam em excesso a arquitetura, sendo que uma abordagem simples resolveria. Realmente a ideia era criar um código simplificado, mas entendi o seu ponto de vista, de que não existe almoço grátis. E tudo deve ser medido e pesado os prós e os contras.